# how to use v-for with v-html

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to step through the lines saved in my database and turn each one into a list from a ordered list but I can't render.

an example of what I want to do is list the "method" on this site:

https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/easy_chocolate_cake_31070

my code:

```js
<script>
import 'highlightjs/styles/dracula.css'
import hljs from 'highlightjs/highlight.pack.js'
import { baseApiUrl } from '@/global'
import axios from 'axios'
import PageTitle from '../template/PageTitle'

export default {
    name: 'RecipeById',
    components: { PageTitle },
    data: function() {
        return {
            recipe: {},
            recipes: []
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        const url = `${baseApiUrl}/recipes/${this.$route.params.id}`
        axios.get(url).then(res => this.recipe = res.data)
    },
    updated() {
        document.querySelectorAll('.recipe-preparation pre.ql-syntax').forEach(e => {
            hljs.highlightBlock(e)
        })
    }
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
    <div class="recipe-by-id">
        <PageTitle icon="fa fa-file-o" :main="recipe.name" />
        <div class="info-recipe">
            <img v-if="recipe.imageUrl"
                :src="recipe.imageUrl"
                height="400" width="100%" alt="Recipe">
            <img v-else
                src="@/assets/article.png"
                height="400" width="100%" alt="Recipe">
        </div>
        <div class="info-ingredients">
            <h2>Ingredients</h2>
            <div class="recipe-ingredients" v-html="recipe.Ingredients"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="info-preparation">
            <h2>Preparation mode</h2>
            <ol>
                <li v-for="(recipe, i) in recipes" :key="i" class="recipe-preparation"
                 v-html="recipe.preparation"></li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Would adding an inner tag within the li work? (ie `<li v-for=...><span v-html=...></span></li>`?

Comment: no, I already tried to do li with span but it didn't work, I'm using the vue editor to save the text to the database and I'm trying to go through each line and put them inside the enumerated list

Comment: Your `v-for` is iterating through the `recipes` data field, but at no point in your code is any value put in that field. Should you actually be looking somewhere in the `recipe` field for the array you want? It might help to see an example of the data returned by your API.

Comment: could you show us the data of your response? With this we can work on a solution.

Comment: thank you for your attention and sorry for the delay in answering but I was able to solve the problem without having to use the v-for